# Regarding Side menu with Tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, menu

I have a scenario like I am using AKSideMenu and Tabbarcontroller both have same items like home, profile etc means home can access from tab bar as well as from side menu.My problem is that access from tab bar is fine but if I select Home from side menu then tab bar item is select correctly but view controller along with tab bar  is not correct(selecting home from side menu display selected home tab bar but view controller is profile view or some random).

Please find code below.

```
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.sideMenuViewController!.contentViewController = nil
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
    self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(getLandingStoryBoard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTicketsViewController"), animated: true)
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
        self.sideMenuViewController!.hideMenuViewController()
    case 1:
    self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(getHistoryStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BiddingHistoryViewController"), animated: true)
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        self.sideMenuViewController!.hideMenuViewController()
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is you're setting the content view controller to a new vc instantiated from the storyboard instead of setting it to the selected view controller of the tab bar controller.

try

```
self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 0
self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(self.tabBarController!.selectedViewController!, animated: true)
```

Either that or the content view controller should always be the tab bar controller.

Comment: Just want to add you probably should handle those optionals better, perhaps with a guard let statement.